# How do I generate a java client from http://api.betdaq.com/v2.0/API.wsdl?

Tags: java, wsdl, wsimport

I'm using jdk wsimport and I get pages of errors that start

---

[WARNING] src-resolve.4.1: Error resolving component 'BaseResponse'. It was detected that 'BaseResponse' has no namespace, but components with no target namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'http://api.betdaq.com/v2.0/API.wsdl#types?schema1'. If 'BaseResponse' is intended to have a namespace, perhaps a prefix needs to be provided. If it is intended that 'BaseResponse' has no namespace, then an 'import' without a "namespace" attribute should be added to 'http://api.betdaq.com/v2.0/API.wsdl#types?schema1'.
  line 17 of http://api.betdaq.com/v2.0/API.wsdl#types?schema1

[WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'BaseResponse' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 17 of http://api.betdaq.com/v2.0/API.wsdl#types?schema1

[ERROR] undefined simple or complex type 'BaseResponse'
  line 17 of http://api.betdaq.com/v2.0/API.wsdl

---

The wsdl goes through visual studio express just fine, so I'm not tempted to tamper with the file.

Answer (score 1):

1. I gave up using wsimport
2. Get apache cxf from http://cxf.apache.org/download.html and install it
3. wsdl2java -autoNameResolution http://api.betdaq.com/v2.0/API.wsdl